# Unable to receive RTP Packets from Wowza Server

Tags: c++, rtsp, rtp

I'm trying to use RTSP to send requests to rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net and receive packets back through UDP. I've used wireshark to listen for packets but no such packets come back to me. Is it possible that my router is not directing them to me? And if so which ports should I port forward on to get the packets to me?

```
SOCKADDR_IN addr;
int addrlen = sizeof(addr);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("184.72.239.149");
addr.sin_port = htons(RTSP_PORT);
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

Connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
if (connect(Connection, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, addrlen) != 0)
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Failed to Connect", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    return 0;
}


void RTSPRequest(std::string requestType) {

CSeq++;
std::string request = requestType + " ";
request += RTSP_SERVER_ADDRESS;
request += RTSP_FILE_NAME;
request += " ";
request += "RTSP/1.0\r\nCSeq: " + std::to_string(CSeq);

if (requestType.compare("SETUP") == 0)
{
    request += "\r\nTransport: RTP/UDP;unicast;client_port= 8000\r\n\r\n";
}
else
{
    request += "\r\n";
    request += session.c_str();
    request += "\r\n\r\n";
}

const char* requestChar = request.c_str();

std::fill_n(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
int sendReturnedValue = send(Connection, requestChar, strlen(requestChar), 0);
int recvReturnedValue = recv(Connection, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);

if (requestType.compare("SETUP") == 0)
{
    std::string bufferString(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    int sessionStart = bufferString.find("Session");
    for (int i = 0;; i++)
    {
        if (buffer[sessionStart + i] == ';' || buffer[sessionStart + i] == '\r')
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            session += buffer[sessionStart + i];
        }

    }
}
```

}

This sends me back a RTSP Response which I receive for all requestTypes, however when I send the play request I dont receive any packets from the server through RTP/UDP or anything that I can find. I've tried searching through all other posts but can't seem to find anyone having the same problem as me.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is the system you have this running on have a public IP address, and not behind a NATing router?

Comment: No it is behind a NATing router